# Changing a data format only for a year column in sql developer

Tags: sql

I have a three tables in my database in every one of them is one 'DATE' format column, when I am changing data format through sql developer preferences It changes the format for the whole database but I want to show only year (YYYY) in the year column by default and other two with the preferences setting, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You tagged this with mysql and with sql-server... which is it?

Comment: There are lots of ways.  You can make the Year column into a integer instead of a Date type.   What have you tried?

Comment: Dates don't have a format. They are stored in a binary representation. The format is applied by your SQL client when *displaying* those values.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting of a date should be done when you query it from the database or even better in the application that is using the data. You shouldn't be trying to control the way it is displayed by changing the database.